# How can I loop a 2D grease pencil animation within a longer animation?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, loop

My goal is to create an animation of a boids particle system. Each boid should be an instance of a 2d grease pencil animation. The problem is that the grease pencil animation stops before the boid animation is done. For regular animations, I know it is possible to make them loop within a longer animation by applying a cycles modifier in the graph editor, but I can't get my grease pencil animation to show up there.

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B3BLQg39Xer5TE7-OEonCzhLLRI66cXT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you want to use a time offset modifier on the gp object

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to wilks' comment above.
It can be done by adding a time offset modifier to the grease pencil object,
enabling `custom range` and setting `end frame` to the length of the grease pencil animation.

[image]

Only problem now is that all the boids loop in unnatural unison, but I guess I'll open another question for that.